# How to aggregate the scores from different rows and return the maximum total scores in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My data set from a CSV file is as below:

```
csv_reader = [['Ali', '34'], ['Ali', '20'], ['Ali', '12.34'], ['Ben', '100.98'], ['Jack', '12.34'], ['Jack', '14.34'], ['Jack', '33'], ['Orlaith', '55.66'], ['Orlaith', '2']]
```

I want to sum up the scores of each person and to see who has the highest scores. So what I expect is as follow:

```
Ben has the highest total score of 100.98
```

Any of you know how to do this? I have tried a few codes, but they just didn't work.

Comment: Could you share the code that you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
csv_reader = [['Ali', '34'], ['Ali', '20'], ['Ali', '12.34'], ['Ben', '100.98'], ['Jack', '12.34'], ['Jack', '14.34'], ['Jack', '33'], ['Orlaith', '55.66'], ['Orlaith', '2']]
cumulative = dict()
for person, score in csv_reader:
    cumulative[person] = cumulative.get(person, 0) + float(score)

max_score = max(cumulative.values())
max_score_persons = [person for person, score in cumulative.items() if score == max_score]

max_score_persons_string = ', '.join(max_score_persons)
print("{0} has the highest total score of {1}".format(max_score_persons_string, max_score))
```

Comment: But you can explain a little bit more about    `for person, score in csv_reader:
    cumulative[person] = cumulative.get(person, 0) + float(score)`    I couldn't quite get this.

Comment: So we are looping through `csv_reader` and unpacking every element into `person` and `score`.  Now we are making forming `cumulative` dict. `cumulative.get(person, 0)` this will check whether is there any entry already or not. If the entry is present it'll provide that value else provides `0`. then we are updating the `person` key with new value. you can print cummulative dict in loop. you'll get it.

Comment: Yeah I understand it now. Thanks a million.